# Isnull with integers and char

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull

I am trying to get the different days from two columns, and if the ab.Final_billdate column is NULL I want to put the string 'UNBILLED'. I tried doing the two below but I get an error.

This is what I have, and I get the error on the string unbilled .

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'UNBILLED' to data type int.

```
isnull(datediff(day,ab.Final_billdate,dd.medate),'UNBILLED') as billing
```

I tried doing a case expression like this, but I get the same error and its because I am trying to put numbers and char in the same output column. Is this possible? Not sure if I need to cast it?

This is the case expression

```
case when  ab.Final_billdate is not null then datediff(day,ab.Final_billdate,dd.medate) else 'UNBILLED' end as billing
```

Desired output:

```
|Billing|
   27
   54
   78
  UNBILLED
```

UPDATE: here is what I did to get what I wanted

```
,isnull(CONVERT(varchar(8), datediff(day,ab.Final_billdate,dd.medate)), 'UNBILLED') AS AgeFromFinalBill
```

Comment: `DATEDIFF` returns an `int`, and `'UNBILLED'` is not an `int`, it's a `varchar(8)`; the error is pretty clear on what the problem therefore is. Don't mix data types. You'll be far better off just using the value `NULL`.

Comment: @larnu Ah, got it! I'll stick with the nulls. Thank you .

Comment: You can cast the int to varchar and that will get rid of the error.

Comment: @smoore4 I'll give it a try . Thank you.

Comment: @smoore4 Thanks. I was able to get the output I wanted . I know its not the best idea but with the end user wanting just the values as is it works.  heres what I did                                                               ,isnull(CONVERT(varchar(8), datediff(day,ab.Final_billdate,dd.medate)), 'UNBILLED') AS AgeFromFinalBill

Comment: exactly.  convert or cast would work:  isnull(cast(datediff(day,ab.Final_billdate,dd.medate) as varchar(8)), 'UNBILLED') AS AgeFromFinalBill

Comment: I really don't recommend converting to a `varchar`, `2` is not greater than `10`; but `'2'` **is** greater than `'10'`. Use the correct datatype for your data.

Answer (score 0):

you can try setting date 1900-01-01 to null values and in a subquery change the value 1900-01-01 to 'UNBILLED'

```
Select CASE WHEN B.billing ='19000101' THEN 'UNBILLED' ELSE B.billing END AS billing
 From
(
Select case when  ab.Final_billdate is not null then datediff(day,ab.Final_billdate,dd.medate) else '19000101' end as billing
FROM Table AS A
) AS B
```